# Tools for testing all aspects of service speed

Tags: centos, php, apache-2.4, performance

We have some strange issues on our CentOS LAMP server where there are occasional severe 4-30 second delays in service despite the server being relatively low load at the time. Is there any tool for analysing the latency of each part of a request individually starting at DNS resolution?

Has anyone got any tips or advice on troubleshooting this issue? We are not experts in this area. I'm expecting if the server is not overloaded it has to be DNS, apache/vhost right?

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect a DNS issue, get yourself a [free Grafana Cloud](https://grafana.com/products/cloud/) account, set up a Grafana instance, configure "Synthetic Monitoring" with HTTP checks from different locations, wait a few minutes, get performance metrics:

[image]

In this case it took 10.1ms to resolve the hostname, 31.5ms to establish a tcp connection, 49.1ms for the tls handshake, 34.8ms for the server to generate a response and 159 microseconds to fetch the response body over the network.

If you got docker at hand, the  prometheus [blackbox_exporter](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/multi-target-exporter/) basically does the same job, even from inside your private network:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 9115:9115 prom/blackbox-exporter
watch "curl -s 'localhost:9115/probe?target=yourwebsite.com&module=http_2xx' | grep probe_http_duration_seconds"
```

which should generate output like this:

```
# HELP probe_http_duration_seconds Duration of http request by phase, summed over all redirects
# TYPE probe_http_duration_seconds gauge
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="connect"} 0.046065283
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="processing"} 0.051462184
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="resolve"} 0.0028130639999999997
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="tls"} 0.051232243999999996
probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="transfer"} 0.000227759
```

I recommend investing some time to get to know Grafana and Prometheus since they are powerful tools, very well documented and there are lots of examples, guides and ready-to-use dashboards to be found on the internet.
You can even fetch detailed metrics about the webserver (apache_exporter), host (node_exporter) and database (mysqld_exporter) to get the whole picture and find your bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul. We're checking out Grafana at the moment 